# Cannot Connect to Geth Web Socket from Other PC on LAN

Tags: go-ethereum, websocket

I have a geth node running on one PC, IP 192.168.0.105 and on my main dev machine IP 192.168.0.102, I'm trying to connect to it via web sockets but keep getting connection not open. Both are on the same LAN.

My program and the connection works fine when I use HTTP provider.

```
const endpoint = 'http://192.168.0.105:8545'; //works fine

//using
const endpoint = 'ws://192.168.0.105:8445'; //connection not open
const wsProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(endpoint);


geth --rpc --ws --wsaddr "192.168.0.105" --wsorigins "*" --wsport "8445"
```